# Creating a specific lens distortion effect in compositor

Tags: compositing-nodes

Excuse me, I see this effect in lots of promotional videos, and I want to mimic it in blender. I've been playing with the lens distortion node in the compositor, but I can't reach it easily... I want to create it without losing the quality of the footage.[image]

Comment: Sorry, are these images of what you want to achieve, or are they what you've produced? In either case, what are the differences between the examples you've seen and what you've created that you would like to eliminate?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett thank you for your reply, bro... these are images I created in Blender using the lens distortion... I tried to mimic the effect that I want to create... the only issue in my process is that I changed the values of the lens distortion node and the scale node very differently... in a way that can't be animated and give a proper result.

Comment: Probably if you can share a node setup (or file with image appended)  ... Also mark the issue iyou want to avoid. Please ...Don't use comment for additional info, use edit under your question.